# Quickest way to learn the useful terminal commands

Tags: mac, unix, terminal

I'm an iPhone developer but surprisingly (even to myself) I am completely unfamiliar with terminal. The only things I know how to do are `cd`, `ls`, `top`, `kill` and the git commands for setting up repositories on github.

What's the quickest way to learn the terminal commands that I might actually find useful?
A list of ones you actually use regularly would be great.

Comment: This is a much too broad question. Everybody's regularly used terminal commands will be different. Just learn as you go -- if you need something, search for it and you will find out.

Comment: Also possible duplicate of: [OS X Terminal Tutorials](http://superuser.com/questions/253195/os-x-terminal-tutorials),

Answer (score 3):

Use the Terminal for things that you would normally use the GUI for. You'll then find yourself hitting Google for instructions on how to do the things you need to do every day, thus learning.